# Setting up Django website on a shared hosting

Tags: python, django, apache, shared-hosting

How do you setup a Django website in a shared hosting?
I've checked the django installation and it is ok

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
>>> (1, 4, 0, 'final', 0)
```

I've followed http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/ section Running Django on a Shared-Hosting Provider with Apache to no avail. Currently the website is like this

```
/home/django_projects/WebsiteName
/sites/WebsiteName.co.id/www/.htaccess
/sites/WebsiteName.co.id/www/dispatch.fcgi
```

The .htaccess file is like this

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(admin_media/.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

and the dispatch.fcgi is like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os
sys.path = ['$HOME/lib/python/Django-1.4'] + sys.path
sys.path = ['$HOME/django_projects'] + sys.path

os.chdir("$HOME/django_projects")
#from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'WebsiteName.settings'
runfastcgi(["method=threaded", "daemonize=false"])
```

It keeps generating error 500, Internal Error when I access the website. What I tried so far are,

```
[1] Changing AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi to AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
[2] Removing AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
[3] Putting the website directory to /sites/WebsiteName.co.id/www/WebsiteName instead of /home/django_projects/WebsiteName/
[4] Do no. 3 and move dispatch.fcgi to /sites/WebsiteName.co.id/www/WebsiteName
```

I'm sorry if this question is so foolish. I'm new to Django. Btw, no 1-4 is not in order. It's just to number what things I've tried so far. Also if I do no. 4, the website shows the content of dispatch.fcgi.

Comment: On shared hostings, provider may have change stuff for security, restriction etc. Try to contact them for configuration assistance

Comment: Do they give you access to the error logs for your url? This would be the best way to troubleshoot. The Apache error.log should show exactly what is going wrong. I'm writing a Python shared hosting platform and that's always the first and last thing I have to look at in these situations.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong in .htaccess and dispatch.fcgi right?

Answer (score 1):

It is more easy deploying with mod_wsgi on shared hosting. I work on [Quijost](http://quijost.com) and we offer a built-in package with Django 1.4 and Python 2.7 under mod_wsgi using nginx as backend.
We wrote a [small tutorial](http://quijost.com/foro/desarrollo-web/ejemplo-de-prueba-index-py-para-django-y-mysql-con-mod_wgsi/) in our forums for mod_wsgi and maybe it is useful for your example with fastcgi.

Comment: the forum is in Spanish and the link no longer works.

Comment: The forum is online, but for higher versions of Django could vary

Answer (score 0):

Response from GoDaddy from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/ehU6lOxKJrU):

> "FastCGI is accessible from Python scripts for our Linux hosting 
>   accounts. We do not allow, however, the addition of a custom FastCGI 
>   handler in our shared hosting accounts."

So I think you're pretty much out of luck. As am I, although I'm trying to convince the customer that having a webfaction account is a good idea, as that supports mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the shared hosting platforms that support python use phusion passenger to run python apps. You can upload your django app to your hosting and use wsgi to run it. As for now, django 2.2 causes problems so you will have to use django 2.1 or lower. I have written a step by step tutorial about it which can be accessed [here](https://blog.umersoftwares.com/2019/09/django-shared-hosting.html).